# Reducing boilerplate in GitHub Actions step

Tags: github-actions

Recently, GitHub [removed](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2950) several C and C++ compilers installed by default on their runners.

Now I need to install these compilers as necessary in a build step. I use the following two steps, one for C and one for C++.

```yaml
      - name: Install C Compiler
        if: ${{ startsWith(matrix.c_compiler, 'gcc-') || startsWith(matrix.c_compiler, 'clang-') }}
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y ${{ matrix.c_compiler }}
      - name: Install C++ Compiler
        if: ${{ startsWith(matrix.cpp_compiler, 'g++-') || startsWith(matrix.cpp_compiler, 'clang++-') }}
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y ${{ matrix.cpp_compiler }}
```

The `if` condition checks if we are actually using a versioned compiler, like `gcc-8` rather than the default of `gcc` (which doesn't need to installed<sup>1</sup>).

I'd like to reduce this boilerplate. For example, both of the steps are almost identical, except in the variable they check `matrix.c_compiler` vs `matrix.cpp_compiler`, their name and the expected form of the compiler `gcc-` vs `g++-`.

Is there a way to avoid this duplication?

---

<sup>1</sup> ... and in fact trying to install the default compilers is not harmless: `install clang clang++` fails on the GitHub runners.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to reduce the boilerplate directly on the workflow file the way GH actions works today. However, you could create a small action to check this for you and install the compilers if needed, then just add a step with this action to your workflow instead of those 2 steps.